# TP-Link AC1300 T3U drivers for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

i am  new to Ubuntu and linux ,can any one help me with the installation of USB wifi adapter drivers on  Ubuntu . please see the link below for the adapter description .

https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/adapter/archer-t3u/?utm_medium=select-local

Thank you

Comment: i know this thread is few months old but if you're still having the issue with your TP-Link T3U / RTL8822BU adapter, you could try installing drivers as I have described in here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1179178/928088 I too have the same adapter, and I've just installed in Ubuntu MATE 19.04 running kernel 5.3.4, and the adapter is working just fine.

Answer (score -1):

[Download](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu) this GitHub file.

Traverse to the download directory then do the following:
Compile using `make` command
Install using `sudo make install`

Note : To unload driver you may need to disconnect the device

Then Run the following commands:

```
cd ~
sudo dkms add ./rtl8822bu
sudo dkms install 8822bu/1.1
```

Reboot the system for new module to be picked up

P.S.
You might need to install `dkms` as well, if not already present.
To install dkms type following: `sudo apt install dkms`

Comment: thank you will try this and see if it works

Comment: for some reason make command doesn't work. is there any chance you can post a step by step process to install this , as i very new to linux its so confusing . your help is appreciated please

Comment: OK, I will edit this but could you also upload a screenshot of error when you type make command

Comment: hi ,i am not able to post screen shot ,not sure why. but when ever i tried sudo make install, it give error *** no rule to make target  'install' stop. thank you

Comment: I had to use 8822bu-1.1 for the last step: sudo dkms install 8822bu-1.1, and then I get the error: Error! Invalid number of arguments passed.
Usage: add <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module> -v <module-version>