# Proper way of installing wifi drivers (rtl8822bu)

Tags: drivers, wireless, tp-link

I have troubles installing drivers for my TP-LINK Archer T3U on Ubuntu 18.04.

Having found out the device ID `2357:012d`, I used [this repo](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu) by @Jeremy31.

Namely, I downloaded the content, cd'ed into it, did `make` and `make install`.

What to do next?

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8822bu
```

gives

```
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtl8822bu does not exist.
```

How to properly install the driver?

Comment: Did you try sudo insmod rtl8822bu.ko and/or sudo modprobe...?

Comment: @ubfan1 Both give not found

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but in my case it compiled to `8822bu.ko`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in the rtl8822bu directory, try

```
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install 8822bu/1.1
```

Comment: The 1st one seemed to work, but the second gave me `Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/rtl8822bu-1.1 does not exist.`

Comment: Try the sudo dkms install command as I just edited

Comment: It worked now, but I got `Good news! Module version v5.1.0-5_17968.20160601_BTCOEX20160411-1400_beta for 8822bu.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 4.15.0-65-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.`. Whereas `lshw -C network` doesn't list the TP-LINK adapter, like nothing happened

Comment: You may need to disable Secure Boot

Comment: hi @jeremy31 would this driver work with kernel 5.3 in Ubuntu 19.04? I've got another USB adapter (RTL8192EU) that needed patch for kernel 5.3 ( https://github.com/CGarces/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/tree/CGarces-patch-1 ) Many thanks.

Comment: @Jags  Try it as I am not using the 5.3 kernel

Comment: @jeremy31 Driver installation didn't go through. Detailed log at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g4JmKbrSJD/ . Error: 'make' all KVER=5.3.4-050304-generic..........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for 8822bu: 1.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.4-050304-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8822bu/1.1/build/make.log for more information. Many thanks.

Comment: Well I found this repo: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU and it worked with kernel 5.3.4

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked very well!

Answer (score 19):

As I am running kernel 5.3.4 in Ubuntu MATE 19.04, for me it was the drivers from [Cilynx's GitHub repo for RTL88x2BU](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU) that worked out OK.

As detailed in the repo, I've installed the drivers using [DKMS installation](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU#dkms-installation) method:

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing mate ;-).

Comment: This one works for me as well in Ubuntu 20.04
https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959

Comment: worked for me as well for Tp-Link Archer T3U AC1300 Mini in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thank you so very much for sharing the proper solution, this solution worked for my Ubuntu 20.04 where I was trying to get TP-Link AC1300(Archer T3U Plus) to work, for some reason originally my system only supported TP-LINK N300-mini USB but now both my Wifi dongles work

Comment: Works with AC1300 on Ubuntu 18.04 for both 2G and 5G.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you and I did as Jeremy 31 suggests in his answer. But even after all that `lshw -C network` didn't list the TP-LINK adapter, like nothing happened. What finally worked for me was switching the secure boot back on.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a 5.4.0-42-generic kernel.