# Trying to install T3U wireless adapter

Tags: drivers

For the last two weeks I have been trying to install a T3U usb wireless adapter. I have read up on the ubuntu tutorial on how the programming works and have managed to install the driver from https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu (I hope I remembered that correctly) with help from various sources on these pages. However the T3U doesn't work because Ubuntu does not detect it. lsusb gives

```
graham@graham-System-Product-Name:~$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f9:0254 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0c31 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. SPIF30x Serial-ATA bridge
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2357:012d  
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I try `lshw`, I get this:

```
graham@graham-System-Product-Name:~$ lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
graham-system-product-name  
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3933MiB
     *-cpu
          product: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 2100MHz
          capacity: 2100MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl cpuid extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch vmmcall lbrv cpufreq
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: RS780 Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fa000000-fbdfffff ioport:d6000000(size=167772160)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:29 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:d8000000-dfffffff memory:d6000000-d7ffffff ioport:ec00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:fbd7c000-fbd7ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 memory:fbe00000-fbefffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: EJ188/EJ198 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: Etron Technology, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:27 memory:fbef8000-fbefffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:28 ioport:d000(size=8) ioport:c000(size=4) ioport:b000(size=8) ioport:a000(size=4) ioport:9000(size=16) memory:f9fff800-f9fffbff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:f9ffe000-f9ffefff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:f9ffd000-f9ffdfff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:17 memory:f9fff000-f9fff0ff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:f9ffc000-f9ffcfff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 13.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:f9ffb000-f9ffbfff
        *-usb:5
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:19 memory:f9ffa800-f9ffa8ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 3a
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: cap_list
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide isa_compatibility_mode_controller__supports_both_channels_switched_to_pci_native_mode__supports_bus_mastering bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pata_atiixp latency=64
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ff00(size=16)
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:16 memory:f9ff4000-f9ff7fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master
             resources: memory:fbf00000-fbffffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg]
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 7
                bus info: pci@0000:04:07.0
                logical name: wlp4s7
                version: 01
                serial: 00:13:46:6e:90:58
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=5.3.0-53-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.1.1.60 latency=168 link=yes maxlatency=28 mingnt=10 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:21 memory:fbff0000-fbffffff
        *-usb:6
             description: USB controller
             product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 14.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=64
             resources: irq:18 memory:f9ff9000-f9ff9fff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k8temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-scsi
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GH60N
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: UG00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-scsi:0
       physical id: 1
       bus info: scsi@3
       logical name: scsi3
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
  *-scsi:1
       physical id: 2
       bus info: scsi@7
       logical name: scsi7
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
  *-scsi:2
       physical id: 3
       bus info: scsi@8
       logical name: scsi8
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

If as suggested I run it as `sudo lshw` all I get is "USB" and it hangs, and it hangs and it hangs and does nothing more (I left it overnight and it was still the same in the morning).
I have been informed by Jos that in lsusb, Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2357:012d is my wireless adapter. I have installed the driver from github (compliments of Jeremyb31) but still nothing happens. One of the paths I tried (sorry can't remember how I did it) says there is "information missing" which is why Ubuntu knows it's there but doesn't know how to use it. Does anyone know how to fix this problem please?

Comment: Bus 008 device 002 is your TP-Link device. You can look up the vendor-device codes of a USB device here: https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/2357/012d

Comment: Thank you Jos. The info shows it to be [Realtek RTL8812BU]. All the posts that I have read say install RTL8822BU drivers which is what I have done. Have I installed the wrong thing?

Comment: I suppose you have rebooted at some point. Is the module loaded? Do `lsmod` or `lsmod | grep rtl8822bu`.

Comment: I have rebooted many times. I see in the lsmod result a few references to codec_realtec. When I type lsmod | grep rtl8822bu , nothing seems to happen, it just goes to the next command line.

Comment: Did you take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178802/proper-way-of-installing-wifi-drivers-rtl8822bu ?

Comment: Yes I have. I followed jeremyb31 advice and I got the message that RTL8822bu is installed.

Comment: You could try the other way (Jags' answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well after a couple of very frustrating weeks trying to install this wireless adaptor, I have found a fix to the problem and I thought I would share it. Aokneufi from the TP-Link Soho community posted the following reply to the question of installing a T4U on kali linux: Ubuntu:

apt update

apt install rtl8812au-dkms

It works for my T3U. I can now relax and enjoy the internet on 5G.