# Missing wifi connection GUI on 22.04 - Realtek 8822BE

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth

[image]

My wifi connection is not working, LAN connection works normally. The Wifi GUI offers me Bluetooth settings, which I believe is a remainder of previously shared bluetooth internet connection (via my phone).

My laptop is Thinkpad E595 running Ubuntu 22.04.

Is there a way to try to reinstall wifi drivers? Does this seem to be a HW problem?

EDIT:

```
Wifi HW information:
Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595
    Physical Slot: 0
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 12
    I/O ports at 2000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Memory at d0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822be
```

sudo dkms status

```
8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.15.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.15.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.15.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new/0.6, 5.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I have tried to install several drivers, so some should be removed?

I think that the main problem now is the unassigned class of the wifi HW? I have not found any way to repair that so far.

Comment: Remove the last line from the file.

Comment: @nobody I have removed the line, now `modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwlwifi` returns `dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi`

Comment: But I can't see how `iwlwifi` is related. What is your wireless hardware?

Comment: @Pilot6 Apparently RTL8822BE by Realtek. iwlwifi is only for Intel HW, right?  How should I proceed then?

Comment: Search for an answer about RTL8822BE

Comment: @Pilot6 I have tried that, nothing worked so far. Is there a way to check if the HW (wifi module) us working? Because `sudo lshw -C network` only returns the Ethernet, not the wifi module - because the RTL8822 has `unassigned class`, it also lists I/O ports as disabled.

Comment: You did a lot wrong things, it will be hard to advise. It is better  to do a fresh install and get the correct driver. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1179178/167850 You installed all sorts of wrong drivers and probably did something else.

Comment: @Pilot6 I thought so. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

first solution is to backup your system and do a fresh install. do not touch the driver files unless needing an update.

the 2nd solution is go Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > then your wifi driver.

you should use an ethernet connection to download the drivers.